# "Update-DataBase" not working using Asp BoilerPlate Module Zero with code first

Tags: asp.net, ef-code-first, boilerplate

I am trying to use project https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero.

In the explainations given on the page I am stuck at

> Run DB migrations (Run 'Update-Database' command from Package Manager
>   Console while ModuleZeroSampleProject.EntityFramework is selected as
>   default project) to create database and initial data.

I receive error message:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly
>   'Abp.Zero.EntityFramework'. (In Visual Studio you can use the
>   Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a
>   migrations configuration).

I have already tried:
- Run 'Update-Database' selecting each projet as default project.
- Run 'Enable-Migrations' selecting each projet as default project.
None of these work.

(I have always work with DB first in the past so this is my first code first try so I am most likely missing something.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. I needed to:

- run Visual Studio as administrator
- use project from 'sample' folder and not 'src' folder